Determine the de Rham cohomology of the unbounded connected component of $\mathbb{R^3}\setminus M_g$.
Let $M_g$ be the compact connected orientable $2$-dimensional surface of genus $g$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Consider the space $$X=\text{unbounded connected component of}~\mathbb{R}^3\setminus M_g.$$
I would like to determine $H^k_{dR}(X),~k=1,\,2,\,3$, for $k=0$ it is obviously $\mathbb{R}$.
First of all, is $X$ a smooth manifold, in order to find its de Rham cohomology?
Other than that, my attempt was to write $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus M_g$ as the union of its connected components and apply the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, but I don't know how they would look like in order to find the intermediate de Rham cohomologies.
It was mentioned that I could use Alexander Duality to solve this problem in a very short manner.

Are you familiar with the one-point compactification?

I do know what is means, but not how to use in this case. Never really saw an argument with one point compactification before.

Well the one point compactification of $\mathbb R^n$ is $S^n$, so you can use that to apply Alexander duality, and then relating the cohomologies of $\mathbb R^n$ and $S^n$ is not that difficult (e.g., using Mayer-Vietoris).
